# Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page

Tags: magento-1.9, forms

We upgrade Magento to 1.9.2.4. Now it worked for a while. When we cleared the cached. We can't log in to the backend anymore. It keeps saying

"Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page."

Our staging site is working fine.

I followed some instructions like increase in_var_input, check cookies and others but didn't work out.

Comment: Have u looked at ur log files? Disable third party apps. Do u still get the same error? That usually means ur session has timed out. So looking for some more info

Comment: Have you tried from multiple computers / using private browsing sessions? Changes to cookie setting can be tricky, and you haven't told us what you've done by "check cookies".

Comment: @AnthonyCicchelli i tried but no luck.

Comment: @LukeRodgers all team tried but we got the same issue.

Comment: I'll see what testing I can come up with tonight. In the meantime run your indexes and clear any cache u can come up with shell..this includes dB sessions..something on ur live server is thinking ur logged in and everything needs to be cleared.

Comment: Have you made any URL changes? Do you have a custom admin url perhaps? The cookie domain may not be correctly configured in the core_config_data table. Jump into the database and run the following: `select * from core_config_data where path like 'web/cookie%' or path like '%admin%url%';`

Comment: @LukeRodgers Yep. We changed the custom Admin url. But we had the problem so we switched it back as default.

Comment: Interesting. Did you switch it over by modifying the xml or using the config settings in the admin panel?

Comment: @LukeRodgers I edited local.xml

Comment: @LukeRodgers Check the query pls. http://screenshot.net/6l4nlil

Comment: Try adjusting the `web/cookie/cookie_domain` for the `scope_id=0` (the admin scope) to be `backend.example.com` instead of `www.example.com`. Perhaps it's having a conflict between the cookie domain for the admin scope vs the actual url of the admin scope. You'll have to flush the caches after this change. Take a backup of the current value first!

Comment: @LukeRodgers i tried to change www.example.com to backend.example.com but didn't work. i changed the custom admin from backend.example.com to www.example.com but till the same.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The record #1733 was set to www.example.com by someone. That caused the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add below line

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

above the line in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/login.html

```
<h2><?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Log in to Admin Panel') ?></h2>
```